# regular expression in jmeter

Tags: regex, jmeter

```
druid_d_c_t=AC6F5384019F7DBA76B7AC009393E539&p_auth=l3wEweSQ
```

I have prepared regex for `druid_d_c_t= druid_d_c_t","(.+?)"` and `p_auth=p_auth=(.*?)&`

after running script im getting output like this:

```
GET https://aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa/druid-web/status?druid_d_c_t=${druid}&p_auth=me6Xr3xa
```

I think `p_auth` is working fine but `druid` is not working. In which part I need to correct it?

Comment: druid_d_c_t","(.+?)" should be 
druid_d_c_t=(.+?)&

Answer (score 0):

Let the Regular expression be `druid_d_c_t=(.+?)&p_auth=(.+)`

For this reference name `reg.druid.auth`,

You will get below output

`reg.druid.auth_g1=AC6F5384019F7DBA76B7AC009393E539`

`reg.druid.auth_g2=l3wEweSQ`